# BOOT_COMPLETE and ExternalStorageState

Tags: android

I need to update some alarms on reboot, but some of the information I need for the updates are in external memory. The BOOT_COMPLETE flag is set before the SD card is completely mounted, so this update cannot be done immediately. Any suggestions on how I can ascertain exactly when the SD card has been mounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED) should do the trick.

Comment: Must have looked right over it at least a few times... Thank You!

Comment: I also just learned that you must change the data scheme to file in the intent filter for MEDIA_MOUNTED <data android:scheme="file"/> , otherwise the receiver will not see the broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is mounted when you receive BOOT_COMPLETE, and set another alarm if it is not. Rinse and repeat if necessary.

Comment: Setting alarms to poll for this would be irresponsible. `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` has been around since API level 1, so it's much better to just register to receive the broadcast.

Comment: Irresponsible, ha :) I guess I missed that one, probably better to use  it then.